# Does Registrar server respond to SIP OPTIONS Method?

Tags: sip

I am making a SIP Phone and have to develop a feature to support multiple registrations. If primary registrar server for phone is down, phone should automatically register to secondary registrar and again go back to primary when primary registrar is active. My question is: how to determine that primary registrar has again become active.
Can I send OPTIONS method from my phone to my primary registrar server, will registrar send response to it like any other proxy server will do? If I get no response from it can I assume that the primary registrar is still not up and I should continue with the secondary registrar.

In SIP RFC 3261 I have read that "SIP method OPTIONS allows a UA to query another UA or a proxy server as to its capabilities." and
"If no response is received for the OPTIONS method the transaction layer can return a timeout error. This may indicate that the target is unreachable and hence unavailable."

Kindly tell me is this the correct way to implement?

Answer (score 3):

The OPTIONS request is widely abused in different SIP software as a NAT keep-alive mechanism. It's an unfortunate situation as OPTIONS requests can incur a significant amount of processing on a SIP server. As such you'll often find SIP Proxy's respond with an Ok response without processing them as per RFC 3261 as a means of avoiding the extra unnecessary processing.

In your case it would probably be sufficient to only worry about failing over if you sent a REGISTER request that did not get a response within the transaction time out period (32s by default). You could configure your SIP Phone to always try the Primary Registrar first when the registration expiry interval is approaching which would mean you're always on the primary server if it's available.

In practice servers should fail very infrequently so if you get too aggressive with your client checking for failures you'll again be generating a lot of unnecessary load. If you are worried about frequent server failures you could reduce your registration expiry from the default 3600s down to 600s or 300s.

Comment: You'll have to determine which is more tolerable while switching back to the primary: a short interval of parallel registrations at the two registrars, or a short interval of no registration. I don't see how the first could hurt, and the second could cause rejected calls. So while registered at the secondary you can keep attempting to register to the primary, and unregister from the secondary on success.

Comment: @Szocske: It won't hurt the client but if the server infrastructure all of a sudden has to cope with twice as many REGISTER requests it will probably be unhappy :).

Comment: If he needs to switch back from the secondary to the primary, that requires an unregister and a register right there, I'm just saying he probably should attempt to register on the primary, and unregister from the secondary on success.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead look at how others have dealt with this.  For example, see the Broadsoft compliance tests for endpoints; they have several tests specifically on how to handle server fallback.  (Also how this interacts with DNS SRV.)